# Does current split when we connect battery in OR configuration

Tags: voltage, batteries, current

Please check the below circuit. Edited the circuit as told.

I have connected two batteries (Max 3A) in OR configuration to the load as shown below.

Once, the power is ON, does the current (assuming the load current = 600mA) split as 300mA and 300mA from battery and battery 2?

or how does the current split?

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgBkuA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Schematic for OP to edit and complete showing the battery and load connections.*

Comment: Are the batteries in series (positive of one to the negative of the other eg. One on top of the other) or parallel (positive to positive and negative to negative, eg. Side by side)? The way it is drawn suggests series but it is extremely confusing since everything is just a wire and the load has three wires going into it. Please redraw using standard schematic symbols.

Comment: Why are there 3 connection to the load?

Comment: Use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar to draw a schematic using the battery symbol and using the resistor symbol for the load.

Comment: Since this drawing doesn't represent any possible circuit, this question remains unclear. Voting to close as such – we can reopen if you finally come around actually drawing a schematic. *Drawing a correct schematic isn't optional. It's as important as trying to speak the same language as the rest here.* Your drawing is perfect: it demonstrates very well how your verbal statement and what you're considering **might** be conflicting, but we don't know which you really mean; that means it's impossible to answer :(

Comment: Also, there's a **very** significant difference in experience level of this question, and the experience level needed for your other questions, which involved transistors, and complex ICs, and oscilloscopes – are you the same person? If not: it would make sense to open an account of your own; we'll try to answer on your level of understanding, but we'd assume you understand as much as the other person using this account.

Comment: I've created part of a proper schematic for you. Please edit and complete the wiring showing clearly if you have connected the batteries in **parallel** (not 'OR') and their connection to the load.

Comment: I have edited the schematic. The batteries are in parallel configuration. While each battery has the capacity to provide 3A of current each by itself. I just want to understand, if the load is only 0.6A, does the current supplied is shared between the batteries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current will be shared equally by the batteries only if they are **exactly identical** to each other. That is almost certainly not the case. In a real voltage source, like a battery, there is a small resistance in series with the voltage source. If the value of this resistance is different for the two batteries then the battery with the smaller resistance will provide more current.